# Expressjs Routes based on an Array of objects

Tags: node.js, express

Trying to setup routes based on an array of objects in ExpressJS, but I'm getting an error when attempting to access the route.

The error is this:

> TypeError: shares[Symbol.iterator] is not a function
>       at router 
>   (C:\Users\rutherfordc.AA\Documents\GitHub\transientComplete\transient-server\routes\shares.js:10:18)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\rutherfordc.AA\Documents\GitHub\transientComplete\transient-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at trim_prefix (C:\Users\rutherfordc.AA\Documents\GitHub\transientComplete\transient-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
>       at C:\Users\rutherfordc.AA\Documents\GitHub\transientComplete\transient-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
>       at Function.process_params (C:\Users\rutherfordc.AA\Documents\GitHub\transientComplete\transient-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
>       at next (C:\Users\rutherfordc.AA\Documents\GitHub\transientComplete\transient-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
>       at expressInit (C:\Users\rutherfordc.AA\Documents\GitHub\transientComplete\transient-server\node_modules\express\lib\middleware\init.js:40:5)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\rutherfordc.AA\Documents\GitHub\transientComplete\transient-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at trim_prefix (C:\Users\rutherfordc.AA\Documents\GitHub\transientComplete\transient-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
>       at C:\Users\rutherfordc.AA\Documents\GitHub\transientComplete\transient-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7

from code like this:

```
 var router = (shares) => {
  for(let share of shares){
    shareRouter.route(`/${share.name}`)
    .get((req, res) => {
      var fileList = [];
      fs.readdir(share.location, (err, files) => {
        for(let file in files){
          fileList.push(file);
          shareRouter.route(`/${file}`)
                      .get((req, res) => {
                       var filePath = path.join(share.location, file);
                        res.download(filePath, `${file}`);
                      });
        }
      }).then(()=>{
        res.render('shareFiles', fileList);
      });
    });
  }
};
```

shares is defined prior to the router function call. What's supposed to happen is that when the application starts, it looks in the config file, imported earlier, get's the list of folders to share and sets them up based on the name property of the object, then goes through each of the files in the folder to create routes based on their file names, which is then passed into a pug template that provides links to the file routes.